# cp: cannot create directory Permission denied

Tags: linux

I have a Folder named "Parser" with in my directory .

I am trying to copy this folder (Parser) from my own directory to my collegues directory under /home/vinay

But i am getting this Exception

cp: cannot create directory `/home/vinay/Parser': Permission denied

These are the commands i executed .

```
-bash-3.00$  cp -r Parser /home/vinay/

cp: cannot create directory `/home/vinay/Parser': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you have no permission to write vinay's home folder.

You can do this either as a root user (if you're in sudoer list), or you can place the file at someplace public (e.g. /tmp) and told vinay to fetch it there.

This is [an article about linux file permissions](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilesp.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much , i have one more question cant Vinay login and do chmod 777 ( Vinay is not a root user)

Comment: @yyyi777: Sure, but make own home folder 777 (universal access by anyone) may not be a good idea. You really don't want to do this. But you guys can cooperate and Vinay can change it back after you copy the file.

Comment: @yyyi777: But I still suggest you put the file/folder in /tmp and make it as 777, so that Vinay can copy it from there. Although linux won't assure that files in /tmp is persistent, but I think it's OK if you just put it there for a while.

Answer (score 2):

The error message reads **Permission denied**, which means you - a user - don't have permission to write to vinay - another person - home directory. [For more reading](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml)